# Php - passing a variable from controller to view

Tags: php, post, model-view-controller, opencart

whenever I run this code i get the error of undefined variable $d, so i noticed i have to pass the variable from the controller to the view. I am new to MVC, hence why i would be grateful if someone helps me with this issue.

This is my implementation so far:
**

### Controller

**

```
class ControllerModuleGetstoreproducts extends Controller{
    public function index() {
        $object = new ModelGetstoreproducts();
        $d = $object->fetch();
        require_once "getstoreproducts.php";
    }
    function returndata(){
        $this->db->select("count(*)");
        $this->db->from("oc_product");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

### Model

```
<?php
class ModelGetstoreproducts{
    function fetch(){
        $sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM oc_product';
        $req = @mysql_query($sql);
        return @mysql_fetch_object($req);
        //return $req;

    }
}
?>
```

### View

```
<p>The total is <?php var_dump($d) ?></p>
```

Comment: is `getstoreproducts.php` your view file?

Comment: @RSTactually it's getstoreproducts.tpl not .php.. yeah that's the view file

Comment: And you're completely sure that this template is included from this controller, and not from somewhere else?

Comment: @SergeyVidusov yes I am sure.

Comment: What if you try to assign something static to $d (e.g. `$d = 'xxx'`) and see if your template picks it up? Looks quite bizarre so far, but I'm sure we're missing something very very simple here.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov I did just now, but it still gives me the same error

Comment: dont use mysql...its deprecated in 5.5, and certainly don't use @ to compress.... and this question doesn't related to MVC...you are simply asking how to pass a variable to a template file, as by default config, I dont think `.tpl` will be interpreted as a php file thus rendering the variable and proper output. try to name your template file to `.php`

Comment: in your code it says .php

Answer (score 1):

Try this update to your files:

**Controller:**

```
    class ControllerModuleGetstoreproducts extends Controller{

    public $data;

    public function index() {
        $object = new ModelGetstoreproducts();
        $this->data['products'] = $object->fetch();
        require_once "getstoreproducts.php";
    }
    function returndata(){
        $this->db->select("count(*)");
        $this->db->from("oc_product");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<p>The total is <?php var_dump($this->data['products']) ?></p>
```

Comment: is this the right way to call a  view file in codeigniter?

Comment: Its not the right way to call view files in the controller. But that was not the question.

The right way in a MVC to call the view is that the controller SET the viewFile but the viewModel returns the output.

Comment: @kaito I have applied all the changes you mentioned, but then I get an error in the line of (public $data) saying: "Undefined property: Loader::$data in.."

Comment: Do you build your own MVC or use someone?

Answer (score 0):

Pass your id from View to Controller and get it into Model.Apply this rule You will not get any kind of error.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I'm not sure whether I really understood what you meant