# php dompdf load variable to view

Tags: php, variables, dompdf

i have this code on controller

```
function btn_create_pdf()
{
    require_once("assets/plugins/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper("A4", "landscape");
    $data = 'Sample Data';
    $html = $this->load->view('report/tbl_pdf',$data,true);
    $tes = $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("Tes.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
}
```

and this tbl_pdf.php

```
<?php echo '<h1>'.$data.'</h1>';  ?>
```

the error on my view is :

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: data

How to passing some variable from PHP controller to DOMPDF ?

Comment: seems like the `$data` variable is out of scope.

Comment: how to fix this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35428391/6468413 take a look at how he did it here. `public $data;` then inside his function he assigns a value to it by `$this->data['products'] = $object->fetch();`

Comment: thanks, it's works :)